# how to define associations and query Self-Referencing Table in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am re-writing an app to utilize sequelize. so far, with the help of documentation. I created following models with associations. the employee table is self-referencing and has a managerid column which points to the id of the employee table. how to create associations and query such table, while joining it with other table like address?

employee model

```
var employee = db.seq.define('Employee',{
    id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    managerId: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER}, 
    employee_name: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING}
    ...
});
employee.hasOne(address);
```

address model

```
var adress= db.seq.define("Adresss",{
    employee_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    ...
});
address.belongsto(employee);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `belongsTo` association to the same model with an alias:

```
employee.belongsTo(employee, { foreignKey: 'managerId', as: 'Manager' });
```

Now you can get an employee along with an associated manager:

```
const found = await employee.findById(id, {
  include: [{
    model: employee,
    as: 'Manager'
  }, address]
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. I am in process of adding more tables and was wondering how to do this part. I opened a new question for this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947004/how-to-join-4-or-more-tables-in-sequelize. please advise if you have any suggestions on this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize associations should always be in two directions. This help to perform a `left join` and a `right join`

```js
employee.hasMany(employee, { foreignKey: 'manager', as: 'Manages', sourceKey: 'id', onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'NO ACTION' });
employee.belongsTo(employee, { foreignKey: 'manager', as: 'manager', targetKey: 'id', onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'NO ACTION' });
```

This way you can make queries as

```js
await employee.findAll({include: ["Manages"]}) // for employees this manager manages
await employee.findAll({include: ["manager"]}) // for the manager of this employee
```