# how to join 4 or more tables in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am rewriting an app , with existing database using sequelize. I have converted existing table, to models in sequelize as below. I have employee table, and access type model, which has read, write, or both in an admin access. all of these access are tracked for employee in and employee access table. but there is a employee group table also, which keeps track , if employee belongs to a particular group and their access type. how do i query using sequelize , to get particular employee access list from employeeAccess table, and also if it belongs to group and if it does access type of that group. so essentially,  need to query by joining 4 tables -  employee, employee access, employee group and then access type table.

1. employee model

```
    var employee = db.seq.define('Employee',{
        id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
        managerId: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER}, 
        employee_name: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING} ...
    });
    employee.hasOne(address);
    employee.belongsTo(employee, { foreignKey: 'managerId', as: 'Manager' });
```

2. address model

```
    var adress= db.seq.define("Adresss",{
        employee_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER}...
    });
    address.belongsto(employee);
```

3. accessType model

```
    var accessType = db.seq.define('AccessType ',{
        id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
        type: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING}....
    });
    accessType.hasMany(employeeGroup );
    accessType.hasMany(employeeAccess);
```

4. EmployeeGroup model

```
    var EmployeeGroup = db.seq.define('EmployeeGroup ',{
        id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
        access_type_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
        employee_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER} ...
    });
    EmployeeGroup .belongsto(employee);
    EmployeeGroup .belongsto(accessType );
```

5. employeeAccess model

```
    var employeeAccess = db.seq.define('employeeAccess ',{
        id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
        access_type_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
        employee_id: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER} ...
    });
    employeeAccess.belongsto(employee); 
    employeeAccess.belongsto(accessType );
```

sql

```
select * from employeeAcess as a 
left outer join employeeGroup as g 
on a.access_type_id = g.access_type_id 
left outer join accesstype as t 
on g.access_type_id = t.id 
where a.employee_id = 1 and g.employee_id = 1;
```

Comment: Can you add a desired SQL query? Are you sure that `EmployeeGroup` should have `employee_id` and not vice versa?

Comment: here is the samle sql, I want to get all the rows for a particular user from employee access table, also, if there exists any rows which match the same employee and same acesss type in the employee group table, i want the group table and finally joint the access type table to get the acutal access type/name.                                     
select * from employeeAcess as a 
left outer join employeeGroup as g
on a.access_type_id = g.access_type_id
left outer join accesstype as t on 
g.access_type_id   = t.id
where a.employee_id = 1 ;

Comment: Please add a formatted SQL sample to your question. It's hard to read it in comments

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Shouldn't `employeeGroup` in SQL query be restricted by `employee_id = 1`?

Comment: yes , you are right. sorry i missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const employeeItem = await employee .findById(1, {
  include: [{ 
    model: employeeGroup,
    include: [accessType]
  }, employeeAccess],
  where: {
    '$employeeGroup.access_type_id$': sequelize.col('employeeAccess.access_type_id')
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. line below is just matching access type id between group and access table. '$employeeGroup.access_type_id$': sequelize.col('employeeAccess.access_type_id')